# Command for demoing my command

Tags: macos, command-line, clipboard

Oftentimes I want to post something to a github bug like

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.195.238): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
64 bytes from 216.58.195.238: icmp_seq=0 ttl=53 time=1064.747 ms
```

Right now I run the command, use `screen`'s `C-a C-[` to highlight the area, `enter` to copy it to that buffer, paste it into `vim`, write it to a file and then `cat` that into `pbcopy`. There has to be a better way.

Is there a command I can run which will `tee` the command I type prefixed with a `$` and all the output to `pbcopy`? Or anything close? I envision

```
$ demo ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.195.238): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
64 bytes from 216.58.195.238: icmp_seq=0 ttl=53 time=1064.747 ms
^C
$
```

and now the original thing I pasted is in my mac clipboard.

Comment: It might help if you added a tag for the OS you're using.

Comment: It felt pretty pertinent to any OS (just swapping `pbcopy` to the equivalent on their OS), but sure.

Comment: Huh? Select the command and its output and hit `Cmd-C` and it'll be in your clipboard.

Comment: @MarkSetchell 1) That is pretty slow to do if I do this often, 2) if it is multiple `screen`s worth of text the scrollback integration of `Terminal` and `screen` doesn't work with the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
script log.txt
ping www.google.com
exit
```

And you'll have your command and output saved in log.txt

**Edit**

Based on your comment,  what you want is

```
command="whatever command you want to run"
echo \$ $command > log.txt
$command >> log.txt
```

I don't think you'll find a single command that does exactly this.

Comment: That's close. It contains my whole prompt as well as a header and footer I don't want for my pastes. Can you deal with those easily?